# What is the best way to remove characters at start of a string in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Considering I have a string like this:

```
var myStr = @"\r\n test";
```

What is the best way to remove the characters like `\r` and `\n` (carriage feed characters) and empty characters

One way I can think of is

```
var trimmedString = myStr.Replace("\r\n", "").Trim();
```

What is the most elegant way to do this ?

Comment: You can use [`TrimStart()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) if its specific characters you want to remove.   If its always going to be whitespace characters like `\r\n` then you can just use `TrimStart()` with no parameters

Comment: `\r\n` is whitespace, so `"\r\n mystring".Trim()` will remove it. The string you are creating though has `\r\n` as a literal on the front, not feed/carriage returns.

Comment: I find elegance in hooking into C libraries.  Unmanaged code is way cooler than managed.

Comment: less code you write, more "elegant" it gets

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString` on a string? Why are you calling `new string` on a string?  Why are you trimming an already-trimmed string? This code makes no sense.

Comment: @EricLippert: I wanted to try out on a Watch window. Thats y

Comment: I don't think that is a valid string constructor.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell if you want the carriage return and line feed characters removed or if you want the literal string: `"\r\n"` removed.

The code you have posted:

```
new string (@"\r\n  test")
```

Is not even valid syntax.  If you want a string literal the syntax is:

```
var someString = @"\r\n some value";
```

The `@` Means that you are *literally* including the string: `"\r\n"` in the output, this means it will not output the escape characters `\r\n` which is carriage return and line feed.

If you want to remove the specific *string* `"\r\n"` you can use `String.Replace` like you were doing, I have cleaned up your code a bit and removed some redundancies:

```
var trimmedString = @"\r\n  test".Replace(@"\r\n", "");
```

If you actually want to remove the *escape characters* from the beginning of the string you need to remove the `@` symbol so its no longer a string literal, then you can use the [`TrimStart()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) method of a string:

```
var trimmedString = "\r\n  test".TrimStart();
```

`TrimStart()` accepts a `char[]` parameter that details the specific characters you want to remove.  However if you do not pass any parameter to `TrimStart()` it will automatically remove *whitespace* characters from the beginning of the string.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fjAQD3)

Comment: I would go on to say that because the OP is using `new string(@"\r\n  test")` that the front of the string does not have whitespace, it is equivalent to doing `"\\r\\n test"` which results in there literally being a `\r\n` at the start of the string.

Comment: Are you sure new string (@"\r\n  test") is even valid syntax?

Comment: @paparazzo Updated my answer because your suspicion was correct.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you wish to remove "raw" escape sequences from your string, you can generalize regex-based approach as follows:

```
var trimmed = Regex.Replace(original, @"^(\\[rntv]|\s)*", "");
```

This removes verbatim `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, and `\v` sequences with optional whitespaces at the beginning of the string. Note that `\` at the beginning is doubled inside a verbatim `@"..."` string literal, meaning that the regex is going to match an escape sequence, not the character it represents.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/S4hYl2)

Answer (score -3):

Your best answer would be to use a regular expression.

```
new Regex(@"(^\s+").Replace("\r\n BLah blah blah   ","")
```

Comment: The best answer would most certainly _not_ be regex

Comment: In what sense is regexp not the correct tool for removing arbitrary strings from the beginning of other strings?

Comment: In the sense that its completely inefficient and inelegant compared to using a built in method (`.TrimStart()`)

Comment: its called overkill. And plus regex tends to be hard to read so I would avoid them for simple tasks like this.